# Generalizing the median of medians algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, divide-and-conquer, median-of-medians

I am asked to find the run time of the general form of the median of medians algorithm for groups of size g. It seems from common examples `g=3,5,7` with `T(n)=T(n/5)+T(2n/3)+cn`, `T(n)=T(n/5)+T(7n/10)+cn`, and `T(n)=T(n/7)+T(5n/7)+cn`, respectively, that the general for an odd number would be `T(n)=T(n/g)+T(1-(n/(2g)*(g+1)/2))+cn`.

However, I am struggling with what to use as median for an even number g where the median will exist between two elements and not actually in the set itself. I am told that I can ignore floors and ceilings. Intuition tells me it should simply be `T(n)=T(n/g)+T(1-(n/(2g)*(g)/2))+cn`, but I can't help but feel that I'm missing something.

Can anyone give advice on how the algorithm might work with groups of even numbers? I think I should be able to find the run time once I understand the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct; when g is even, you can express the run-time as T(n) = T(n/g) + T(3n/4) + cn, which is your expression simplified; the inductive proof that this is O(n) whenever g > 4 is the same regardless of whether g is even or odd.

To see why this equation is true, it's easiest to think about how the expression for T(n) with odd g is derived. **We can assume that our input list A has no duplicate elements, without loss of generality** (by either slightly modifying the algorithm, or by replacing every element A[i] with the tuple (A[i], i) and using lexicographic comparisons). This makes the analysis much easier.

Now, Median-of-Medians Quickselect's run-time is based on the three things it does:

1. Call itself recursively on the 'medians' list of size `ceil(n/g)` to find the **median-of-medians** `M`
2. `cn` work to group items, partition the list around `M`, and find the median of each small group-of-g, and
3. Call itself recursively on either the partition with all elements less than `M`, the partition with all elements greater than `M`, or immediately return.

Ignoring the ceil and an additive `O(1)` constant, this gives `T(n) = T(n/g) + T(New Partition Size) + cn`. What's the largest the New Partition Size can be? It's `max(# elements less than M, # elements greater than M)`.

When `g` was odd, we had that half of the `n/g` groups had medians less than `M` (so `(g-1)/2`, plus `1` for the median, elements in that group are less than `M`), and half had medians greater than `M` (again, giving `(g+1)/2` 'greater than `M`' elements for each such group).

Since you're defining median of an even list as the arithmetic mean of the two middle elements, this gets even simpler: half of the `n/g` groups have medians less than `M`, and exactly half the elements of each such group is less than its median and thus less than `M`; the same logic works for greater than. This means we have eliminated at least (`half of n/g times g/2`), or `n/4` elements, leaving us with `3n/4` as the maximum New Partition Size and `T(n) = T(n/g) + T(3n/4) + cn`.